# I want to have a page that collects information from the user, and i want to take that information and use it on other pages and classes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it necessary to store this to a file and isolated storage, or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not have to. You can place common data in your 'application', which will be accessible everywhere via the [Application.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property. Alternatively, if you use the MVVM pattern, you can set the `DataContext` of the `RootFrame`, this will ensure that all pages shares the same data context.

See this blog post I wrote for a [nice simple MVVM WP7 example](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/).